# Using List to Look up values in event.detail.fields

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have used apex to return a list of fields from an opportunity field set.  What I want to do is use this field set to check the fields are populated on my lightning-record-edit-form.

If I am looping through the list of fields with this:

```
For(var i=0; i<=this.requiredFields.length-1; i++){
```

How do I check the event.detail.fields for a matching value and check if its popualted.

Thank you!!

Apex Class:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static list<string> getOppFieldSets(string lob){
    List<string> requiredFieldsFinal = new List<string>();
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> requiredFields = new List<Schema.FieldSetMember>(
      Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fieldSets.getMap().get(lob).getFields());
  
      for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : requiredFields) {
        requiredFieldsFinal.add(f.getFieldPath());
      }
    system.debug(logginglevel.info, '$$ here is the requiredFieldsFinal ' + requiredFieldsFinal);
    return requiredFieldsFinal;
  }
```

Javascript:

```js
//get the correct field set on load
connectedCallback() {
    if(this.lob){
        this.queryFieldSets()
    }
}
queryFieldSets(){ 
    getOppFieldSets({lob: this.lob})
    .then(data => {
        this.requiredFields = data;
    })
}
```

HTML

```html
<lightning-record-edit-form layout-type="Full" record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Opportunity"
    onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess} onerror={handleError} onload={loadEdit} density="comfy">
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update"
            label="Save Record">
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_large">
        <div class="Header1">
            <lightning-output-field field-name="Name" ></lightning-output-field>
        </div>
     </div>
 </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

The code that I am having an issue with is below.. how do I use my variable named field1 to lookup in event.detail.fields to find the matching field and check if it has been populated.

```
for(var i=0; i<=this.requiredFields.length-1; i++){
    var field1 = this.requiredFields[i];
    var fieldToCheck = event.detail.fields.field1;
    console.log('here is field1 ' + field1);
    console.log('here is teh fieldToCheck ' + fieldToCheck);
```

Comment: can you please show the apex class together with your javascript and html please, so that we can understand better

Comment: I added the apex and javascript where call the apex.  thanks!

Comment: Could you please add HTML code too? The code related to the lightning-record-edit-form.

Comment: Added.  thank you!

Comment: You have no lightning-input-field, do you want to create them dynamically using the fieldset?

Comment: Sorry, I shortened the html to remove the 30 fields I have.  The field set has 10 fields which I want to check to make sure all are populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build an array of object with two properties, `apiName` and `required`, then loop over it in the template to create the lightning-input-field elements with the related attributes setted. This way you'll leverage the oob validation.

```js
inputFields;

queryFieldSets(){ 
    getOppFieldSets({lob: this.lob})
    .then(data => {
        this.requiredFields = data;
        const inputFields = [];
        // Repeat the following line for each input field.
        inputFields.push({ apiName: IMPORTED_FIELD_ABC.fieldApiName, required: data.includes(IMPORTED_FIELD_ABC.fieldApiName) });
        //...
        inputFields.push({ apiName: IMPORTED_FIELD_XYZ.fieldApiName, required: data.includes(IMPORTED_FIELD_XYZ.fieldApiName) });
        this.inputFields = inputFields;
    })
}
```

HTML

```
<template for:each={inputFields} for:item="field">
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2" key={field.apiName}>
        <lightning-input-field field-name={field.apiName} required={field.required}> </lightning-input-field>
    </div>
</tempalte>
```

If you have several section in your form, you could have an array for each section, the logic is the same.

A different way to achieve validatio could be running it once the form is submitted:

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    let hasError = false;
    for (const requiredField of this.requiredFields) {
        // if a required field is missing
        if (!fields[requiredField]) {
            hasError = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hasError) {
        // notify the issue
    } else {
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you Ruben!